Python format printing objects from a list
I'm trying to make a simple to do list app, in this I need to print a list, but I cant figure out how to make it go from ['test'] to test
I haven't tried anything because I have no clue where to start. I have asked a discord group but they recommended to come here.

To print elements from a list individually in Python, you can use a for loop to iterate through the list and print each item. For example, for item in my_list: print(item) will print each element on a new line.

Each element in a list is given an index which starts at zero and increases for each additional element in the list. So if your list is my_list = ['test', 'test2'], then example_list[0] would be 'test' and example_list[1] would be 'test2'.

It sounds like you really need to find a good book/tutorial/class on Python that will teach you basic things like this.

"I have asked a discord group but they recommended to come here.": Such a recommendation is either naive or mischievous. Stack Overflow is generally not a good place to ask newcomer questions.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

have you tried this !
for item in yourList:
    print(item)

